# Variable stored Object Property name used to reference said Object Property name

Tags: variables, object, properties, powershell-4.0

In Powershell can one reference a Object's property through the contents of a variable? To allow changing of variable contents to change logic, instead of changing the logic directory. See the below for a working example using the $CorAorMTime variable, where this functionality would be handy:

```
$DirectoryIterationDepth = 1

$CorAorMTime = "creationtime"

$FilesDatedAfter = -7

$Path = @()

foreach($Level in 1..($DirectoryIterationDepth+1))
{
   $Path += $PathToTargetDir + ("\*" * $Level)
}

get-childitem $Path -force | where-object {$_.$CorAorMTime -gt ((get-date).adddays($FilesDatedAfter))}
```

Comment: what is the catch here ?

Comment: Sorry. Don't understand. What catch?

Comment: What issue you are facing on this ?

Comment: where-object seems to be working on Modified time, not Creation time.

Comment: are you getting any error, or its giving null value ?